# How to list all 'at' jobs without root privileges?

Tags: linux, batch, queue, at

For listing jobs added by **at** and **batch** I use **atq**, but it lists only my jobs. I can run **atq** with root privileges and then it lists jobs from all users.

How can I list all jobs **without** root privileges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be the answer you want, but strictly speaking, you could boot a Live CD and use that to look at the files in /var/spool/at (or equivalent).

The privacy and security provisions of Unix/Linux does not allow you to do what you want. The at files are stored by default with "other" read privilege set to off.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I can start some deamon/program in cron/etc with root privileges that provide this data for non-root users. Is there any tool that do this? Or maybe you have some suggestions how to do it with scripts?

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { setreuid(0, 0); argv[0] = "/usr/bin/atq"; exec(argv[0], argv); return 0; }

Comment: Assuming it was compiled by root and chmoded to setuid, this would run atq for a regular user as root, in a similar manner as sudo /usr/bin/atq. But it would still run with root privileges.

Comment: Ok, it works, but I changed exec() to execv() (it didn't compile with exec() ). Thanks!

I think that to get this informations without root privileges (at least when running a something-like-atq) I could add a cron job that grabs this data as root and stores it in a file which is readable for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

you might create a custom little program that runs atq and give it suid root.

beware that:

- if you do something wrong, it will be very easily exploitable to gain root access
- you can't suid a script, it has to be an executable